# Почему не адаптируется Slick слайдер в сетке на ФлексБоксах?

Tags: адаптивная-верстка, flexbox, slick.js

Здравствуйте коллеги.

Есть страница со слайдером
[185.159.131.173/nosb/reports-page.html](http://185.159.131.173/nosb/reports-page.html)
На настольной версии - все хорошо, но стоит начать сужать окно - слайдер перестает реагировать на ширину окна, ломается и перестает держать высоту и в целом ведет себя странно.

ПОДОЗРЕНИЕ на display:flex у родительского контейнера. НО!! вся сетка стоит на флексах, это flexboxgrid.

Убедительно прошу пройти мимо советчиков из разряда "юзай флоат"

Прошу, помогите приструнить слайдер.

Заранее огромное спасибо!!!

Answer (score 0):

width: 100% на  .report__main - контролируем ширину контейнера.